# How to center the text inside a Button regardless of drawableLeft?

Tags: android, button, textview, drawable

I want the text centered in the `Button`. But whenever I add `android:drawableLeft` xml attribute to the `Button`, it offsets the text. How can I fix that?

[image: share button]

The only way I managed to fix it is by setting a negative number in `android:drawablePadding`:

[image]

But I'm looking for a cleaner solution to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up going with the lesser of the evils, and that's placing the drawable and the text inside `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Button.ButtonGray"
    android:id="@+id/share_button">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_share"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        style="@style/TextNormalWeight"
        android:text="@string/post_share"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `RelativeLayout` then receives click events and acts and looks like a button.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately that is the `Button` behaviour and I agree with you that negative padding is kind of a dirty hack, so I'll propose two other hacks that to me sounds a little less dirty because they rely on expected behaviour (negative padding although works it's not by design):

- set `android:paddingRight` on the button to the size of the drawables
- create a drawable with the same size of the left drawable but with all transparent pixels and put as right drawable.

Answer (score 0):

android:gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: Nope. The `gravity` in a button style is already `center` (not just center_vertical).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no clean way to do this. One fairly straightforward way is to set a transparent ColorDrawable  of equal size on the opposite side of the button.

```
val drawableSize = button.height // adjust this as desired of course

realDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawableSize, drawableSize)

val emptyDrawable = ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT).apply {
    setBounds(0, 0, drawableSize, drawableSize)
}

button.setCompoundDrawables(realDrawable, null, emptyDrawable, null)
```

Answer (score -1):

It works with:

```
android:gravity="center"
```